# I Can't Change my Default Interactive Shell from bash to zsh

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, chsh

Basically I want to change from bash to zsh so I ran the command

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

It then asks me for my password to change the shell but when I enter it it says

```
chsh: no changes made
```

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: That means you're already using `zsh` as your default shell. Did you logout and login again? Why is this tagged [tag:powershell]? Are you on Windows?

Comment: I still have bash as the default shell since it pops the message to update my account to use zsh, the tag was my bad sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since changing your shell requires updating `/etc/passwd`, it must be done by `root`. Use

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh $USER
```

Also make sure `/bin/zsh` is listed in `/etc/shells`.

Just in case, login (with the old, working shell) in a text terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2) while you `chsh` and logout/login via the GUI, in case you need to fix something.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!

Comment: @Ingo what did? Waltinator: the `chsh` command should be setuid root, and allows you to change your own shell. Root access is only needed to change somebody else's shell.

Comment: If my answer "solved my problem", please Accept it, by clicking on the checkmark.